# Why creating an OutlineHandler, and passing this outline handler to the ConverterProperties I get NullPointerException with convertToElements method?

Tags: itext7

I need to use

- **HtmlConvert.converToElements(InputStream,converterProperties)**

But I'm getting **NullPointerException** when I add **converterProperties.setOutlineHandler(outlineHandler)**

Is there any reason for this?? I meant, is this a normal behavior?

Becuase when I use other methods like converToDocument I don't have any issue.

Comment: The outlines are created on a document. However, when you just create the elements, there is no document (yet), hence there is nothing to attach the outlines to. iText has no idea whatsoever what you're planning to do with the elements; you shouldn't expect that iText can magically guess which document you have in mind.

Comment: Of course! how I did not think it! Thank you very much for the clarification @BrunoLowagie

Comment: This being said, I'll create an internal ticket to provide a better error message rather than just throwing an NPE.

Comment: It will be so helpful for us! Thank @BrunoLowagie